# Pointers difference

Tags: c++, pointers

Say I declared an array`int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};`, when I do `(*(&a+1)-a)`, it prints `5`.

I came to know that `*(&a+1)` takes me to the end of an array, and as `sizeof(a)=20`.

So does pointer arithmetic takes me ahead of size of allocated container?

Also I am little bit confused on pointer arithmetic, why it prints `5` rather than `20`?

Comment: Your example of an array is not a declaration of an array. Your example of "when I do" uses an unspecified variable `a` that can't be an array of numbers (if it were then you would evaluate the expression *number* `- a`). Voting to close as lacking a reproducible example.

Comment: The simple answer is *"past the end of the array"* is `5` integers (20-bytes) beyond `a`. `&a+1` is a pointer to (*address of*) an `int[5]` that is one-past `a`, so `*(&a+1)` is an `int[5]` and on access is converted to a pointer to the first element (`int*`) 5-integers beyond `a`. It essentially simplifies to `a + 5 - a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your program above, a and &a will have the same numerical value,and I believe that's where your whole confusion lies.You may wonder that if they are the same,the following should give the next address after a in both cases,going by pointer arithmetic:

### (&a+1) and (a+1)

But it's not so!!Base address of an array (a here) and Address of an array are not same!  a and &a might be same numerically ,but they are not the same type. a is of type * while &a is of type (*)[5],ie , &a is a pointer to (address of ) and array of size 5.But a as you know is the address of the first element of the array.Numerically they are the same as you can see from the illustration using ^ below.

1 2 3 4 5
  ^           // ^ stands at &a

1 2 3 4 5
        ^     // ^ stands at (&a+1)

1 2 3 4 5
^             //^ stands at a

1 2 3 4 5
  ^           // ^ stands at (a+1)

Hope this will clear the doubts.

Comment: A bit more formally, the name `a` **decays** into a pointer to its first element in most cases. It is **not** the name of a pointer; it's the name of an array. For example, given `void f() { char a[20]; std::cout << sizeof(a) << '\n'; }` would show be the size of the array, i.e., 20, not the size of a pointer. You're absolutely right about the difference between `a` and `&a`, and in your example `(a + 1)`, `a` decays into a pointer. +1.

Answer (score 4):

The result of pointer arithmetic is is in units of the dereferenced type.

If you have a pointer to an `int` then the units will be in `int` elements.

If you have a pointer to an `int[5]` then the units will be in `int[5]` elements, which are exactly 5 times as big.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer arithmetic is not same as arithmetic operation (addition/subtraction) between hexadecimal values. Following example demonstrates both.

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    int * pintx = *(&a + 1);
    int * pinty = a;
    cout << "pintx = " << pintx << endl;
    cout << "pinty = " << pinty << endl;
    cout << "Pointer Arithmetic : Ans = " << (*(&a + 1) - a) << endl; 
    // Prints 5    
    cout << "Pointer Arithmetic : Ans = " << (pintx - pinty) << endl; 
    // Save as above, Print 5

    cout << "Hexadecimal Subtraction: Ans = " << ((int)pintx - (int)pinty) << endl; 
// Prints 20, as you expect

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Robin-Khurana does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

> So does pointer arithmetic takes me ahead of size of allocated container?

No. Not the "size of allocated container", but the size of the dereferenced type. `sizeof(a)` is 20 because as an object the type of `a` is `int[5]` instead of `int*`, and the type of `&a` is `int[5]*`. It will be clearer if I rewrite your example as below:

```
typedef int Int5[5];
Int5 a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

> Also I am little bit confused on pointer arithmetic, why it prints 5 rather than 20?

`(*(&a+1)-a)` is 5 because in this case `a` is interpreted as `int*`.

Comment: Note that `int` is not guaranteed to be 4 bytes. It often is, but be wary of hard-coded assumptions about the sizes of built-in types. For a system with 8-bit `char`, `int` has to be at least 2 bytes; there is no upper limit to its size.